# google-API-Client returning empty response from google admin sdk

Tags: javascript, api, google-api-client, google-admin-sdk

I'm trying to pull users from google admin sdk. I have the following set up:

**function**

```
public function getGoogleUsers ()
    {

        putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=' . resource_path('assets/keys/X-X-X-X-X-X-X'));
        $client = new \Google_Client();
        $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
        $client->setApplicationName('X-X-X-X-X');
        $client->setScopes(array(
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member.readonly',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member.readonly',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.orgunit.readonly',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.resource.calendar.readonly',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.alias.readonly',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.userschema.readonly'
        ));
        $client->setAccessType('offline');

        $client->setSubject('X-X-X-X-X');

        $response = new \Google_Service_Directory($client);

        return json_encode($response);
    }
```

I have set up **OAuth 2.0 client IDs**, I have enabled **domain wide delegation**, i have enabled the **admin sdk api**, i have added **permission for the above scopes**. But for some reason I keep getting an empty response.

[image: empty response]

Comment: Are you encountering an error `ApiProjectMapError` as seen in the screenshot?

Comment: That error is unrelated.

Comment: I didn't add the proper scopes.